# Can't loop through an array when using $.parseJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this code which creates a table when I click on a button. The code you see below works perfect, when I click my button, the table is created in the target div. But the problem is that when I replace the index of `dataArray` from `0` to `i` in the for loop, the table doesn't show and I get this error in the console of Google Chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Device_Name' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".button").click(function()
    {
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',

        data = {'action': clickBtnValue};

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) 
        {
            dataArray = $.parseJSON(response);
            var tbody = '';
            var theader = '<table><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td><td>Id</td></tr>\n';

            for(i = 0; i <= dataArray.length; i++)
            {
                tbody += '<tr>';
                tbody += '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>';
                tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[0].Device_Name + '</td>';
                tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[0].Device_Id + '</td>';     
                tbody += '</tr>\n';     
            }

            var tfooter = '</table>';

            document.getElementById('dataTable').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;         
        });
    });
});
```

What can't I use variable `i` as an index for my array?

Comment: show response JSON as well

Comment: try: for(i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++). Looping from zero to the length of the array implies you're reading beyond the end of array.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use `i` as an index?

Comment: Exactly what @Alan said; You are looping while i is smaller than or equal to the length of the array. Since arrays start at 0, but counting starts with 1 you are running the loop one too many times.

Comment: `console.log(response)`....

Comment: @adeneo `dataArray[0]` is working for the OP. It's when `0` is replaced with `i` it stops working: *'But the problem is that when I replace the index of dataArray from 0 to i in the for loop'*

Comment: @George - just noticed, didn't catch that part.

Comment: In the future, easily debug problems like this using console.log. `console.log('i: ', i, ' item[i]:', item[i])`

Comment: Should be noted that modern browsers support `forEach`, and that you can add the `json` dataType at the end of the `$.post` and have jQuery parse it for you.

Comment: ... and that jQuery actually have a `$.each` method that will iterate anything.

Comment: How couldn't I have seen this myself :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is because you are doing 1 too many loops. Arrays are 0 indexed so you want to loop up to length - 1.

This will then allow you to use `i` for accessing the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
{
    tbody += '<tr>';
    tbody += '<td>' + (i+1) + '</td>';
    tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[i].Device_Name + '</td>';
    tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[i].Device_Id + '</td>';     
    tbody += '</tr>\n';  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When iterating through a zero-indexed array, you need to use less than ( < ), not less than or equal to ( <= ). The last element in the array will be at index: length - 1.

Changing:

```
for(i=0; i<=dataArray.length; i++)
```

To:

```
for(i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can user each method to loop through json object, ie:

```
$.each(dataArray, function (index, element){
    alert( element.Device_Name );
});
```

Updated..

Comment: updated it after your comment. this is the a better solution anyhow. @George